# setAttribute in change event listener does not update the view

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component, event-listener

I am trying to use a "default" string for a text field which is constructed within its own web component. By "default", I define a string that gets fully reprinted when the text field gets emptied. setAttribute on the input element reference does change the text field value **but does not update the view**. Accessing the value through the event's target on the other hand does so, even though both refer to the same element - as I understand it at least.

The issue is obvious in the provided snippet.

Thanks in advance.

```js
class editForm extends HTMLDivElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["data-source"];
  }
  constructor() {
    self = super();
    let firstTerm = document.createElement("input");
    firstTerm.setAttribute("type", "text");
    firstTerm.setAttribute("class", "form-control mr-2");
    firstTerm.setAttribute("aria-label", "Source Term");
    firstTerm.setAttribute("value", this.getAttribute("data-source"));

    firstTerm.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
      let input = e.target.value;

      if (input.trim() === "") {
        //this line alone does not suffice to update the printed text field value
        firstTerm.setAttribute("value", this.getAttribute("data-source"));
        input = this.getAttribute("data-source");
        //commenting out the following line results in the data-source string
        //not being reprinted within the text field
        e.target.value = input;
      }
    });

    self.appendChild(firstTerm);
  }

}
customElements.define("edit-form", editForm, {
  extends: "div",
});
```

```html
<div is='edit-form' data-source='test'></div>
```

Comment: Note that ``extends: "div"`` (Customized Built-In Elements) are not supported on Safari, Apple still refuses to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the `input` or `keyup` event.

The `change` event on an <input> only fires after an Enter keypress or when the field loses focus

source: [Change Event:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

[image]

Also note: Your `data-source`, because of the `data-` prefix becomes a data attribute

So `this.getAttribute("data-source")` can be written as: `this.dataset.source`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: I agree this is possibly more appropriate for this use case. I still do not understand why setAttribute("value",..) is not enough to update the view, even though firstTerm and event.target reference the same HTML element.